# Изменить класс при нажатии

Tags: html, jquery

Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на  менялся класс.

Код не работает при нажатии вообще.

```js
$(function(){

  $('.#playradio').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#playradio').removeClass('fa fa-play-circle fa-5x').addClass('fa fa-stop-circle fa-5x');
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<i id="playradio" class="fa fa-play-circle fa-5x" style=" color:#ffaa39;left: 50%; cursor: pointer; position: absolute; top: 1%"></i>
```

Comment: У вас ошибка в строке `$('.#playradio')` .... точку уберите... чтоб был выбор по ИД `$('#playradio')`...... и раз это не ссылка, то `e.preventDefault();` лишнее..........и можно не писать `removeClass('fa fa-play-circle fa-5x').addClass('fa fa-stop-circle fa-5x')` целиком все классы не надо перечислять, достаточно только нужный `removeClass('fa-play-circle').addClass('fa-stop-circle')`

Comment: Большое спасибо.

сделал вот так:

$(function(){

  $('#playradio').on('click', function(){
    $('#playradio').removeClass('fa-play-circle').addClass('fa-stop-circle');
  });
});

и всё равно не работает. 
При нажатии я смотрю в браузере код, и изменений не происходит.

Comment: а каких изменений вы ждете? во первых в теге нет текста хоть какого нибудь....а во-вторых...может вы хотели менять цвет? так для этого стили `css` надо прописать

Comment: Я жду, что при нажатии на <i> изменится его класс. 
Я хочу заменить fa-play-circle на fa-stop-circle

Comment: ок. а как вы определяете, что вы ткнули в то место, куда надо,если никаких опозновательных знаков нет? Даже сниппет показывает чистую страницу...... Код который приведен в комментарии - рабочий.... просто вы что-то не то делаете

Comment: Сама иконка <i> с классом fa-play-circle - и есть объект на который кликаю. 
Это шрифт - http://fontawesome.io/
Нужно чтобы при нажатии на  Play  - http://joxi.ru/Rmzzq41fWwalLm  значёк менялся на Stop.

Comment: смотрите..я скопипастил код из комментария в ответ...и он работает.....чудо =) напомню `e.preventDefault();` не нужен!..возможно дело просто в нем)......А может у вас в принципе ошибка вываливается в консоли и вы об этом умалчиваете))

Answer (score 1):

порядок классов не сохранится, в остальном всё ок:

```js
$('#playradio').text($('#playradio').attr("class")); // для демонстрации: переносит класс в содержимое тега <i></i>
$('#playradio').click(function() {
  $('#playradio').removeClass('fa-play-circle').addClass('fa-stop-circle');
  $('#playradio').text($('#playradio').attr("class"));  // для демонстрации
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<i id="playradio" class="fa fa-play-circle fa-5x" style=" color:#ffaa39;left: 50%; cursor: pointer; position: absolute; top: 1%">1</i>
```

- строки с комментариями - только для демонстрации работоспособности кода.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```js
$("#play").on("click", function() {
  $(this).hide();
  $("#stop").show();
});
$("#stop").on("click", function() {
  $(this).hide();
  $("#play").show();
});
```

```css
#stop {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="playradio">
  <div id="play" class="fa fa-play-circle fa-5x"><i class="fa fa-play-circle fa-5x" style=" color:#ffaa39;left: 50%; cursor: pointer; position: absolute; top: 1%"></i></div>
  <div id="stop" class="fa fa-stop-circle fa-5x"><i class="fa fa-stop-circle fa-5x" style=" color:#ffaa39;left: 50%; cursor: pointer; position: absolute; top: 1%"></i></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  $('#playradio').on('click', function() {
    $('#playradio').removeClass('fa-play-circle').addClass('fa-stop-circle');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<i id="playradio" class="fa fa-play-circle fa-5x" style=" color:#ffaa39;left: 50%; cursor: pointer; position: absolute; top: 1%"></i>
```